# Struggling with the append method for JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

This is the code I am struggling with. It is refusing to amend the JTextArea with the new text. I create the window and set it to visible in the main function of the project.
Thanks ahead.

EDIT:
By refusing, I mean the JTextArea will simply not display the text. It just stays empty. I'm not getting and error or exception. It is all logical.

```
class Window extends JFrame{

protected JTextArea text;

public Window() {

    setTitle("Create a list of names");
    setSize(500,400);
    Container containerPane = getContentPane();
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();

    text = new JTextArea(10,50);
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(256,256) );
    text.setEditable(false);

    JScrollPane scrollText = new JScrollPane(text);
    scrollText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    jp.add(scrollText);

    containerPane.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    text.append("Test");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
      Window w = new Window();
      w.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by refusing? Is it pointing any error or exception?

Comment: Posted code looks reasonable to me. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Your current code is NOT compileable or executable since there is in main() method. Also, don't use setPrefferedSize(). Each component will determine its own preferred size and the layout manager will use this information to position/size the components properly.

Comment: sorry. By refusing, I mean the JTextArea will simply not display the text. It just stays empty. Im not getting and error or exeption. It is all logical.

Comment: I assume you're sure `text.append` is being called?  That is, your `System.out.println` is actually printing the text field data you expect?

Comment: @ChrisChevalier please could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Also called SSCCE as camickr said) which demonstrates the issue? I.e. create an example program which we can copy-paste, compile and see the same error as you, that way we are more able to help you.

Comment: @ajb The println is printing the text as it should, which is why it is confusing me.

Comment: @Frakcool I Update the question to hopefully follow the MCVE rules.Feel free to mention if I used it incorrectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column width of `50` is greater than the width of the frame so the added text appears offscreen. Reduce its value to fit the parent window

```
textArea = new JTextArea(10, 35);
```

Don't use `setPrerredSize`. Let the layout manager do its job and call [`pack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--) after all components have been added.